# similar to Android INSTALL_REFERRER in Iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, app-store

I am searching which is similar to **INSTALL_REFERRER** in android for Iphone but not found any thing. My requirement is when any user share app link from my app in social networking I will add some parameters with app link. And if some one else will download and install that app then the user which was shared the app link will get rewards ie: Virtual currency etc.

The problem is how I receive my added parameters in Iphone client I will implement the logic. Is there any thing similar to **INSTALL_REFERRER** in iphone as well.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm after your question as well, in case you can't find the answer, try using the walk around method: use some kind of device blueprint to identify the user (like IP, IMIE ...)